# Как изменять программно активность HubSection?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

```
<Hub x:Name="Hub1" x:Uid="Hub" Margin="0,76,0,0">
            <HubSection x:Name="hb1" x:Uid="HubSection1" Header="Карта" Foreground="#FF317A8F" IsHeaderInteractive="True">
                <DataTemplate>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>
            <HubSection x:Name="hb2" x:Uid="HubSection2" DataContext="{Binding}" Header="Местоположения" Foreground="#FF317A8F" IsHeaderInteractive="True">
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="gridm">

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>
        </Hub>
```

как программно переключать HubSection? Например если что то случилось в момент когда активная hb2, hub перелистывался на hb1??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все очень просто

```
Hub1.ScrollToSection(hb1);
```